# I'm getting these error while I try to send sms from my frontend using twilio in nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio, sms, twilio-api, sms-gateway

I'm trying to send OTP from my frontend through a custom API URL which is using a nodejs backend server to trigger the request. but I'. getting the following error.

backend code:

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

router.post("/notification", (req, res) => {
  const type = req.query.type || "sms";
  const ph = `+${req.query.ph}` || "";
  const email = req.query.email || "";
  const reason = req.query.reason || "notification";
  const msg = req.body.text || "";

  if (type === "sms" && reason === "auth") {
    const OTP = getRandom(1000, 2000);
    console.log(`OTP is - ${OTP}`);
    client.messages
      .create({
        body: `Hi, Im Sandip. OTP is - ${OTP}`,
        from: "+12012994953",
        to: ph,
      })
      .then((message) => res.send({ ...message, otp: OTP }))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err, "err"));
  }else{ ...some other logic }
```

On this URL I'm requesting these parameters

```
http://localhost:4000/api/auth/notification?type=sms&reason=auth&ph=918697836806
```

The error I'm getting in console

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Twilio'
    |     property '_accounts' -> object with constructor 'Accounts'
    --- property 'twilio' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\controller\authController.js:122:30
    at Promise_then_fulfilled (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:766:44)
    at Promise_done_fulfilled (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:835:31)
    at Fulfilled_dispatch [as dispatch] (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:1229:9)
    at Pending_become_eachMessage_task (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:1369:30)
    at RawTask.call (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\asap\asap.js:40:19)
    at flush (D:\Edureka\Projects\Full Stack Projects\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\asap\raw.js:50:29)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`res.send()` tries to stringify the object you give it. According to [twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node), you want

```js
 .then((message) => res.send({ message: message.sid, otp: OTP }))
```

rather than a destructuring of the whole `message` object coming back from their API.

**Edit**:  Try this. I think it does what you want. You should be able to tell from the console.log what you're sending back.

```js
 .then((twilioResponse) => {
   message = twilioResponse.sid
   message.otp = OTP
   console.log(message)
   res.send(message)
 } )
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But can't I add my otp field inside the response from the twilio and send the whole as one object to my frontend. I tried this ```.then((message) => res.send({ message, otp: OTP }))```. it send ```{message: {.....},top:{....}}``` it worked but need ```.then((message) => res.send({ other fields of message, otp: OTP }))```